# HTML formatting error on Umbraco workflow notification emails

Tags: asp.net, umbraco

I've posted this in the Our Umbraco forum (http://our.umbraco.org/forum/ourumb-dev-forum/bugs/30914-HTML-formatting-error-on-workflow-notification-emails) but would like to expand the audience as I need a quick resolution to this problem.

There appears to be an issue with the HTML used in workflow notification emails, property names are displayed but their values are not visible. The HTML content is there and if I save the source as an .htm file and view it in Firefox the values are displayed (although in the wrong location).

The HTML is generated from the **sendNotification** function in the **umbraco.cms.businesslogic.workflow** namespace, I am using **Umbraco v4.7.1.1** and this problem was noticed in **Outlook 2007**.

Has anybody else encountered this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that this issue has been logged with Umbraco (http://umbraco.codeplex.com/workitem/26577) but has not been addressed.

The fix is a simple code change, for my current project I have decided to download the CMS source code and make the change myself. This works but throws up maintenance issues e.g. ensuring my change is not wiped out during a CMS upgrade.